# how would I be able to select a genre my book is in when I create a book

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, attributes, relational-database

I don't know how to title my question, I'm sorry haha. I am building an app where users sign up as authors or reviewers. Authors upload their books which belong to genres. Users that are reviewers find the books they want to review by genre. When I create a book resource with an author user, how would I create a way of selecting multiple genres that book belongs to in the new book form??

I am learning ruby on rails development and am very early in my understanding of it. I so far have devise for my app and am using enum to create roles for users when they sign up so that they're either and author or reviewer. I've also made a users controller so that when they sign up they get redirected either to an author profile or reviewer profile. Next step is figuring out how to create genres that books belong to. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Hi. Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Also--A manual for a design tool or api for recording designs is not a manual on how to design.)

Comment: Lol, not sure if I understand. But yes. I need to study more literature. I used to program in rails years ago. Then life happened, I got laid off my web developer internship, went back to college, and forgot most of what I learned. Six years later I've come full circle. I haven't arrived by any means. But I'm making strides. I appreciate the stack overflow community big time. I've had many questions answered and it often yields answers through my Google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the database. We'll create a [has-and-belongs-to-many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relation,

```
create_table :books do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :genres do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :books_genres do |t|
  t.references :book, foreign_key: true
  t.references :genre, foreign_key: true
end

add_index :books_genres, [:book_id, :genre_id], unique: true
```

Now to add association for the models:

```
# app/models/book.rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :genres
end

# app/models/genres.rb
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

As for the User Interface, we could use standard [HTML Multiple Select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp), but it's really not user friendly, so we'll go with checkboxes.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :books # this is too much, but you will probably use other actions anyway.

# app/controllers/books_controller.rb
def new
  @book = Book.new
  @genres = Genre.all
end

# app/views/books/new.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: @book, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>

  <% @genres.each_with_index do |genre, i| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "book[genre_ids][#{i}]", genre.id %>
    <%= label_tag "book[genre_ids][#{i}]", genre.name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now we have to do some magic in the controller as we'll receive the genre_ids as a hash (`{"0" => "1", "1" => "3"}`), this will transform that to `[1, 3]`

```
# app/controllers/books_controller.rb
def book_params
  params[:book][:genre_ids] = (params[:book][:genre_ids] || {}).values.map(&:to_i)
  params.require(:book).permit(:name, genre_ids: [])
end
```

And finally we can have our action to create books

```
# app/controllers/book_controller.rb
def create
  @book = Book.new(book_params)

  if @book.save
    redirect_to @book
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

To see any checkboxes, you'll need to have your genres in database. You can easily do this through `rails console`:

```
%w[Adventure Tragedy Fantasy].each { |g| Genre.create(name: g) }
```

Checkboxes might not be the best user interface for that either, you may want to google for user friendly multiple selects, but this should explain you the basics of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: That is some great code right there. Since I'm a newbie some things were a little confusing at first but j understand it at last. I think where you merged the attributes of the book params and genre_ids from the join table was fascinating. Didn't know you could do that. And using the console to build a word array for genres. Brilliant! Yeah, I may do more research on a user friendly way of selecting multiple genres when building a book. But for now this gets me on my way! Thanks for exposing me to some good programming.

Comment: You're welcome :) I've made a small adjustment in `book_params` as I killed the `name` parameter by accident. If you use a library that wraps standard select, this magic with parameter transforming will not be needed as you should simply receive an array of ids straight away.

Comment: Your code worked flawlessly. Again, I've very impressed to say the least. You've been doing this for too many years, I can tell haha. Keep on keeping on! One day I'll be on that level too....maybe xD